# How to use function of order_set if I am using filter instead of get?

Tags: python, django, filter, get

When I use get instead of filter in views.py, I get error saying customer object isn't iterable, which I understand. But using filter instead of get doesn't allow me to user 'order_set' function (also in views.py), showing up with an error message: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'order_set'. How can I workaround this?

views.py

```
def customer(request, pk):
customer = Customer.objects.filter(id=pk)
order = customer.order_set.all()
context = {'customer': customer, 'order':order}
return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)
```

customer.html

```
           <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>

            {% for i in customer %}
            <tr>
                <th> {{i.email}}</th>
                <th> {{i.phone}}</th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
           </table>
           <table class="table table-sm">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Date Orderd</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
            {%for order in order%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{order.product}}</td>
                <td>{{order.product.category}}</td> 
                <!-- the above is chaining -->
                <td>{{order.date_created}}</td>
                <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                <td><a href="">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home),
path('products/', views.products),
path('customer/<str:pk>', views.customer)
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the customers, when you are fetching a specific instance?

Comment: I want to render attributes of Order class (in model.py), of each customer with order_set.